# Force pushing commits with different commit message - getting 'Everything up to date' notice

Tags: git

I accidentally pushed some 'in-progress' code to origin. I since committed and pushed some other changes to origin. After pushing everything and noticing the mistake of pushing in-progress code, I noted the commit hashes for the important commits and did a `git reset --hard HEAD^^^^`, then I cherry-picked my commits, removing the in-progress commit from the stack, I then completed my in-progress commit and updated the commit message. I then force pushed to origin and got a message saying that everything is up to date.

Although, the git history and commit messages in origin are totally different than what I have locally. I'd like to force push and have origin reflect exactly the same commit messages that I have locally.

It seems the only difference currently is the commit messages.

Is there a way to update the remote commit messages with the local messages even if there isn't a `diff`? or if there is no real difference between origin and local, there is no way to update the remote commit messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a different commit hash (since the message enters in the making of the hash), your commit is just *another commit* to your remote repo, **even with an entirely identical tree of files**.

Yes, after the cherry-picking episode, force-pushing to the remote was indeed the way to go, so if you had an "up-to-date" message when pushing, it means that something here is not what you think. Either you're not pushing the branch you intend to, or there's something else you didn't describe.

Can you show how you pushed and the output you had?

You can also check with `git log --all --oneline --decorate --simplify-by-decoration` to see where your different refs are pointing to (namely, your branch and its remote counterpart).

Comment: I am pushing to the intended branch and it can entirely be the case that the remote code and local code is in sync - so maybe 'Everything is up to date' is actually correct. What *doesn't* seem to be up to date is the commit message, which I'd like to update on the remote branch. Although, I suspect if there isn't a `diff` between local and remote, there is nothing to 'push' - which is exactly the issue I am facing. I am trying to `force push` knowing that the only difference is the commit message (not the code), although it won't let me do that for some reason.

Comment: No. The up-to-date message isn't the result of some comparison on code base, it's the commit hashes that count. With rewritten history, the new commit hash you're pushing (most recent) is compared to the old ref. If the new one does not have the old one in its hostory in order to fast-forward the old ref, the push is rejected, whatever the state of files described in the commits.

Comment: The hashes are different locally than they are remotely and so are the commit messages. Not sure why this is. Although I am attempting to push to the correct remote branch.

Comment: @AnchovyLegend Can it be a misunderstanding about default push config? Can you show the exact command you use to push, and maybe the output of `git config -l | grep <your_branch_name>` to check where it is set to push?

Comment: You were right! I uncovered the issue when doing a `git branch`, It said `(no branch, rebasing staging)`. I checkout out the working branch as a new branch `staging-backup`, then checked out staging, did a `git reset --hard HEAD^^^^^` and then merged in `staging-backup` and forced pushed to `staging`, that took care of it and updated the history correctly!

Comment: @AnchovyLegend Yay! I'm becoming a better rubber duck, ha! ;-)